# Setting up H2 DB programmatically

Tags: java, h2

I'm trying to programmatically update H2 in memory database in my code. For some strange reason I cannot seem to be able to get the create a schema or table. No errors, it just doesn't seem to work. I can create a table using the method below but not a schema

```
Statement stmt = null;
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");

try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9090/mem:test", "sa","")) {

    //STEP 3: Execute a query
    System.out.println("Creating schema in given database...");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String sql =  "CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    System.out.println("Created schema in given database...");

    stmt.close();
```

Comment: If you can create a table then it seems it'd working. How do you know the it fails, if there's no error?

Answer (score 1):

The H2 jdbc url, to my knowledge, should be "jdbc:h2:mem:test". Try with this one. See if it helps.